# Интеграция Angular 6 и Chart.js

Tags: angular5, chart.js

Питаюсь подключить `Chart.js` к `Angular 6`, но после запуска приложение получаю ошибку `Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item core.controller.js:123`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал `Angular CLI: 6.0.8` для создание проекта.

Файл package.json:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл angular.json:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и остальные файлы: `app.module.ts`, `app.component.ts`, `app.component.html`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно и как это можно решить!!!

Comment: Скрины кода тут не приветствуются, лучше копипаст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так думаю, что в первый параметр `new Chart(ctx,{...})` надо передать `DOM` элемент `canvas`. Вы же передаете строчку `myChart`.

```
const ctx = 'myChart';
```

Передайте `canvas` - и все у вас заработает.

Answer (score 0):

id элемента и значение переменной, которую вы передаете в chart должны быть одинаковыми.

Например:
app.component.html

```
<div>
  <canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
const ctx = 'pieChart';
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...})
```

В примере, значения id и переменной ctx - "pieChart".